# От чего зависит память, выделяемая объекту при его создании?

Tags: c++, выделение-памяти

Мне интересно, от чего зависит память, выделяемая объекту при его создании?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

От размера объекта, разумеется. В частности, от суммы размеров его полей (ели это структура или экземпляр класса) или от разрядности системы (если это скалярный тип). Чтобы точно определить, сколько памяти выделяется под конкретный объект, используйте конструкцию *sizeof (объект)*. Только учтите, что если одно из полей объекта - указатель, на который вешается динамически созданный массив, то такой метод даст неточный результат: он определит размер указателя (4 байта в 32-битных системах, 8 байт в 64-битных), а не размер выделенного под массив места.

Comment: а что здесь неточно?

Answer (score 4):

Под объект выделяется столько памяти, сколько он занимает. Это зависит от количества, расположения и размеров его полей. Размер объекта не всегда совпадает с суммой размеров его полей.

Например, если класс использует виртуальные функции, то он потяжелеет на размер указателя.

Также существует такая штука, как выравнивание членов в структурах. Компилятор может вставить пустоту между полями, чтобы следующее поле было выровнено, то есть имело адрес, кратный 2, 4, 8 - в зависимости от выбранного выравнивания. Обращение к невыровненным данным снижает производительность, а на некоторых архитектурах приводит даже к ошибке.

Также следует учесть, что если объект использует динамическую память, то размер объекта от этого никак не изменится. Занимать место будет только указатель. То же самое и с контейнерами. Сколько миллионов бы там элементов не находилось, они будут иметь всегда один и тот же размер.

Поэтому, чтобы узнать размер объекта, лучше использовать оператор sizeof, а не считать его самому.